# How to send Email in PHP or Java

Tags: java, php, email

I have a database where I have to store data from a file. But the problem is every night the file is sent to a particular email address.I want to write a program using PHP or Java that will read the email and parse the files and store in Database. I am not finding the idea how can I automatically sense whether an email is received with a particular subject and download file from that email.
Does anyone used such program using PHP or java.

For example I received the email With subject "data". My php code will sense that email is received with subject desired and then download the file.
Then parsing would not be a problem.The same solution in Java would be appreciated. I'll go for Java or PHP where I can get a nice solution to this.

Comment: You'd likely need to poll the mailbox with something like POP3 or IMAP.  I'm sure both Java and PHP have code samples and/or client libraries which can be used to interact with those protocols.

Comment: look for JavaMail. It's a basic implementation with everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP: 
   [This is a nice class for receiving mails with IMAP.](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) 
For Java: (@Shloim answer) 
   [Use JavaMail, as it's fairly straight forward.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_checking_emails.htm)